# If I console.log(this.get('controller')), is there a simple way to figure out that particular controller's name?

Tags: ember.js

I have a view that triggers an action, and when that action is called I want to send something to the controller by calling `this.get('controller').send('someAction')`. However it is never called. I was wondering if I have `console.log(this.get('controller')`, how could I find what controller it is being sent to? Could I get the console to say something like `App.ControllerName`?

### -

---

## Edit

---

I created jsBin of what I am attempting to do http://emberjs.jsbin.com/tonorida/1/. In short, when I the file upload box changes, I want it to fire an action in the controller.

Comment: Interesting question, I was thinking about it too today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `this.get('controller').toString()`, so in these scenarios you'll have the following outputs:

1- Declared controllers:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend();
controller.toString(); // outputs <App.IndexController:ember224>
```

2- Auto generated controllers:

```
// App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend(); 
// ember will generate a controller for us
controller.toString(); // outputs (generated index controller)
```

Comment: I am calling **this.get('controller')** from inside of a view. Would that make a difference? I am getting the view name **App.ImportFileView:ember519** when I type **this.get('controller').toString()** from inside a view action.

Comment: Can you show how you are declaring that view? `Ember.Component` subclasses has the `controller` property as the view itself

Comment: [http://emberjs.jsbin.com/tonorida/1/](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/tonorida/1/) is a jsbin of what I am trying to do

Comment: `Ember.TextField` is a subclass of `Ember.Component` so you don't have access to controller property, you can use the `sendAction` to dispatch your action http://emberjs.jsbin.com/tonorida/3/edit